# Program works in Python 2.7 but not in 3.10

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, sockets, python-3.10

So basically i made a LAN Rock Paper Scissors in python.. i managed to make it work just fine on python 2.7 but when i run it with 3.10 it seems to get stuck on an infinite loop for no reason.. (i have included a comment (#) in the code to show you where it gets stuck)

heres the 3 Scripts

Server Script 2.7 (Server Script is the same for both so this is the 3.10 too)

```
import socket
import threading


Host=("localhost")
Port=9090

Server=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
Server.bind((Host, Port))
Server.listen(5)

Clients=[]
Players=[]
PlayersMoved=[0,0]
Moves=[0,0]



def Broadcast(Result):
    for Client in Clients:
        Client.send(Result)


def Game(Moves):
    # 1=Rock, 2=Paper, 3=Scissors
    if Moves[0]==1:
        if Moves[1]==1:
            Result="Tie"
        elif Moves[1]==2:
            Result=str(PlayersMoved[1]+" Won")
        elif Moves[1]==3:
            Result=str(PlayersMoved[0]+" Won")

    elif Moves[0]==2:
        if Moves[1]==2:
            Result="Tie"
        elif Moves[1]==3:
            Result=str(PlayersMoved[1]+" Won")
        elif Moves[1]==1:
            Result=str(PlayersMoved[0]+" Won")

    elif Moves[0]==3:
        if Moves[1]==3:
            Result="Tie"
        elif Moves[1]==1:
            Result=str(PlayersMoved[1]+" Won")
        elif Moves[1]==2:
            Result=str(PlayersMoved[0]+" Won")
    print ("im here7")
    Broadcast(Result)


def GetMoves(Client):
    while True:
        try:
            Message=Client.recv(1024)
            PlayerMove=""
            Parted=False
            for i in range(len(list(Message))):
                if Message[i]==":":
                    Parted=True
                    print ("im here2")
                    pass
                elif not Parted:
                    PlayerMove+=list(Message)[i]
                    print ("im here1")
                elif Parted:
                    Move=int(Message[i+1])
                    print ("im here3")
                    break


            if PlayersMoved[0]==0:
                PlayersMoved[0]=PlayerMove
                Moves[0]=Move
                print ("im here5")
            else:
                PlayersMoved[1]=PlayerMove
                Moves[1]=Move
                print ("im here6")
                Process2=threading.Thread(target=Game, args=(Moves,))
                Process2.start()

        except:
            index=Clients.index(Client)
            Clients.remove(Client)
            Client.close()
            Player=Players[index]
            Broadcast(str(Player+" left!").encode('ascii'))
            Players.remove(Player)
            break


def Connections():
    while True:
        Client, Address=Server.accept()
        print("Connected with ",Address)
        Client.send('NICK'.encode('ascii'))
        Player=Client.recv(1024).decode('ascii')
        Players.append(Player)
        Clients.append(Client)
        print("Nickname is ",Player)
        Broadcast(str(Player+" joined!").encode('ascii'))
        Client.send('Connected to server!'.encode('ascii'))
        Process1=threading.Thread(target=GetMoves, args=(Client,))
        Process1.start()



print ("Server is listening...")
Connections()
```

Client 2.7

```
import socket
import threading


Nickname=raw_input("Choose your nickname: ")

Host=("localhost")
Port=9090

Client=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
Client.connect((Host, Port))

def Receive():
    while True:
        try:
            Message=Client.recv(1024).decode('ascii')
            print (Message)
            if Message=='NICK':
                Client.send(str(Nickname).encode('ascii'))
                print ("im here1")
            else:
                print ("im here2")
                print(Message)
        except:
            print("An error occured!")
            Client.close()
            break

def Write():
    while True:
        MyMove=str(Nickname+": "+raw_input("1=Rock, 2=Paper, 3=Scissors:"))
        while MyMove!=str(Nickname+": 1") and MyMove!=str(Nickname+": 2") and MyMove!=str(Nickname+": 3"):
            MyMove=str(Nickname+": "+raw_input("1=Rock, 2=Paper, 3=Scissors:"))
        Client.send(MyMove.encode('ascii'))
        break


Receive_Thread=threading.Thread(target=Receive)
Receive_Thread.start()

Write_Thread=threading.Thread(target=Write)
Write_Thread.start()
```

Client 3.10

```
import socket
import threading


Nickname=str(input("Choose your nickname: "))

Host=("localhost")
Port=9090

Client=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
Client.connect((Host, Port))

def Receive():
    while True:
        try:
            Message=Client.recv(1024).decode('ascii')
            print (Message)
            if Message=='NICK':
                Client.send(str(Nickname).encode('ascii'))
                print ("im here1")
            else:
                print ("im here2") #(it gets stuck here)
                print(Message)     #(it gets stuck here)
        except:
            print("An error occured!")
            Client.close()
            break

def Write():
    while True:
        MyMove=str(Nickname+": "+str(input("1=Rock, 2=Paper, 3=Scissors:")))
        while MyMove!=str(Nickname+": 1") and MyMove!=str(Nickname+": 2") and MyMove!=str(Nickname+": 3"):
            MyMove=str(Nickname+": "+str(input("1=Rock, 2=Paper, 3=Scissors:")))
        Client.send(MyMove.encode('ascii'))
        break


Receive_Thread=threading.Thread(target=Receive)
Receive_Thread.start()

Write_Thread=threading.Thread(target=Write)
Write_Thread.start()
```

Comment: Smells like `bytes/str` confusion.  What does that `print(Message)` produce?  How about `print(repr(Message))`?

Comment: General advice btw: don't code against Python 2, it's a dead language and has been for many years now.  Just upgrade to Python 3 everywhere and don't look back.

Comment: @Samwise the output with the print(repr(Message)) is like this im here2
''

im here2
''

im here2
''

im here2
''

im here2
''

im here2
''

im here2
''

im here2
''

im here2
''

im here2

Comment: Looks like you're getting empty messages.

Comment: @Samwise I agree but thats what they teach as in school.. so.. either i like it or not.. i still have to work with it

Comment: An empty message mean the connection has been closed, you should break out of the loop.

Comment: @Barmar yeah.. but why doesnt this happen with 2.7 thats what i cant understand.. its the same library.. besides.. i dont understand why it sends empty messages.. it shouldnt.. as far as i can tell

Comment: @Barmar well the server is running just fine.. how is the connection closed? Besides.. if i break out of the loop.. i wont get any more messages from the server.. so when the winner is broadcasted.. the client wont get the message

Comment: The server code does `list(Message)` which returns a list of characters in Python 2 but a list of integers in Python 3.